# Array of children - state not updating

Tags: reactjs

This is a bit of a vague question but let me try via pseudocode.  If I create an array of child objects in a parent object:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        this.state = {kids: [<Child/>,<Child/>]};
    }
    render () {
        return <div>{this.state.kids[0]}{this.state.kids[1]}</div>
    }
}
class Child extends React.Component {
...
}
```

If I do a setState on a Child within the Child component does/should that change the parent kids array?  My thinking is that the elements of that array *are* the Children so changing a Child should change the element.  Am I wrong in my understanding?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a specific callback that happens when the child updates that triggers the parent, then the parent won't get that update.

This is why most React developers have adopted a smart and dumb component pattern: You really shouldn't have the state of the children managed in both components. The parent component should provide callback functions as props to the child components that handle any sort of changes that would apply to that child and then update its own state accordingly, once its state is updated it will pass the necessary parts down to each child component as props.

Your goal should be to have the least amount of state spread across your components and try to keep state managed in one component and the rest just receive props. A great article on this is: http://jaketrent.com/post/smart-dumb-components-react/